# I am getting an error in django saying it might be an issue with circular import but I am not sure how to fix. I think my code is correct

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-2010, cmd

I am very new to coding so I will explain what I did step by step.

I created a virtual environment in command prompt and then I installed django in that. Then, I opened the project in vs code and activated the new environment in the terminal.

I then create calc by running the command:

```dos
python manage.py startapp calc
```

This my urls.py file in calc:

```python
from django.urls import path

from . import views #from all import views

urlpatterns = [  #setting up the mapping
path('',views.home,name='home') #homepage can be represented by '' or '/'
]
```

and this is my views.py file:

```python
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
return HttpResponse("Hello world")
```

and my project url.py file:

```python
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
path('', include('calc.urls')),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

but when i run the command - python manage.py runserver I am getting this error:

```
File "C:\Users\maya\env1\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 725, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name)) from e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'calc.urls' from 'C:\\Users\\maya\\myprojects\\firstproject\\calc\\urls.py'>' 
does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see the 'urlpatterns' variable with valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

I don't think there is anything wrong with the code so I don't know what the problem is. I have tried to kill the terminal but even doing that doesn't disconnect me from the server. And, this error is not going no matter how many times I run the `python manage.py runserver` command

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not sufficient to identify the issue.
I can suggest change the code to solve the issue.

calc/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world")
```

calc/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views  # from all import views

urlpatterns = [  # setting up the mapping
    # homepage can be represented by '' or '/'
    path('', views.home, name='home')
]
```

project urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('calc/', include('calc.urls')),
]
```

don't forget to add app in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py file of project.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'calc',
]
```

Now run the code and access the url in browser: http://127.0.0.1:8000/calc/